# change with column that is updated based on is null

Tags: sql, sql-update

Hi I have an update query where if one field is null then I want value goes to another field

here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
UPDATE Table SET
CASE WHEN Column1 is NULL
THEN Column2 = @Update 
ELSE Column1 = @Update 
END;
```

Now this does not work as I get an error on the word case but is there a way to do what I am try to accomplish? I know it could be done if I used two update statements with a where but was wondering if it could be done in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax for CASE in SQL statements. CASE must return an expression, it cannot contain a statement in pure SQL.

```
update Table 
  Set Column1 = Case when Column1 is NULL Then NULL Else @Update END,
      Column2 = Case when Column1 is NULL Then @Update Else Column2 END
```

Comment: This would work but column1 always has data in it, so for my needs it would need to be testing case when Column2 is null and then if column2 is not null then just update column1 with column1's current value. Thanks for the answer. I hadn't thought of using case like that